# driver ODBC does not work with MySQL

Tags: mysql, odbc

I want use MySQL database in R environment. I am using Ubuntu OS. To do this I should install unixODBC or iodbc and install odbc driver for MySQL. I encounter with error in R when I want connect to database: file /usr/lib/odbc/libmyodbc.so not found. But of course that file is in that directory. I googled everything I think. the only clue I have that it is probably problem with mysql odbc driver, it does not see the file (why?). Any help is appreciated.

There is work around to this problem - use rmysql package for R. Nice!

Comment: Don't know the answer, but appear "rmysql" is the keyword for what you need, and a package on CRAN.

Comment: +1 @Micheal: Great, welcome to Stackoverflow - posted an answer to your question below since it worked and will make the page easier for others to quickly read. Next to the answer I'll post is a checkmark on the left, if you clik that it'll let others know that was the answer that solved the problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "RMySQL" package on CRAN is what you need, here a link for more info:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/

Found the above by Googling "R MySQL".

(NOTE: This answer was first posted as a comment, but worked, so I'm posting it as the answer to clean up the page.)

Answer (score 0):

You have different driver for MySql its probably mySQLconnector.Try using this .You dont need to use ODBC drivers for this.